# Generate a report and execute it inside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a button inside update panel, which creates a report and the report is given as a page response. WHen  I didn't have update panel the report was generated and downloaded, but now when I introduced update panel, the report is generated but I am not getting that in the browser. What should I do.

```
  using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
                        {
                            writer.Write(success);
                            writer.Write(error);
                            writer.Write(warning);
                            Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
                        }
                        Response.End();
```

I am using update panel to use update progress.

Error in `response.end()`

```
Get the system.web.httpresponse object associated with the system.web.ui.page object. 
This object allows you to send HTTP response data  to client and 
contains information about the response
```

What does this means

Update:

```
 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server">
     <ProgressTemplate>
      <div style="width: 338px; position: relative; top: -420px; left: 80px" class="">
         <b>Please Wait...</b>
          <img runat="server" id="ajaxLoader" style="background-color: White; width: 338px;"
                                src="styles/images/loadImage.gif" alt="loading" />
      </div>
         </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
     <asp:Button ID="btn_upload" CssClass="UploadBtncss" runat="server" Text="Upload"
                            OnClick="upload_Click" />
```

Answer (score 3):

try using Trigger for postback trigger

```
<Triggers> <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID=”btn1” />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks @AshokD  putting <Triggers> inside the UpdatelPanel does the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, you can't use Response.Write (and a number of other Response methods) inside an UpdatePanel. There are workarounds, but it is essentially down to the nature of the partial update used by the update panel. It doesn't play nice with Response.Write.

If you google it you will find alternatives (such as moving the Response.Write out of the UpdatePanel or using a PostBackTrigger)

This page seems to give a reasonable explanation:
http://www.jnouel.net/post/2009/07/06/ResponseWrite-and-UpdatePanel.aspx

Comment: If the button is not inside the update panel, then how will the update progress work

Comment: It won't. Off the top of my head I can't think of a simple way around this. One option is to do the progress with Javascript instead and have that purely client-side. Or you could do something clever like creating the file somewhere in the first request and then presenting a link to download it afterwards.